# Eigenvalues of A/r^2 + B*r^2 potential

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, eigenvalues, numerical-value

I would like to find the energies of a system in a matrix way. The system has the following Hamiltonian: 
**H1 = -1/2*Laplacian +(A1/r^2)+(B1*r^2)** 
I use radial functions as basis functions: Psi1[r_, n_] = (2 E^(-(r/n)) Sqrt[n1!/(-1 + n)!] Hypergeometric1F1[1 - n, 2, (2 r)/n])/n^2

This is a problem from Landau's book on quantum mechanics, it's on page 124 (or p. 138 in pdf file) (Problem 4) (book: [https://power1.pc.uec.ac.jp/~toru/notes/LandauLifshitz-QuantumMechanics.pdf](https://power1.pc.uec.ac.jp/%7Etoru/notes/LandauLifshitz-QuantumMechanics.pdf)).

For simplicity, I consider the case when **l=0** and for convenience, I have written down the Hamiltonian to dimensionless units. 
Thus, the energies of such a system have the form: E1n=Sqrt[B1/2]*(4*n + 2 + Sqrt[8*A1])

The units of energy I used to simplify the Hamiltonian are: E0=m/hbar^2, so energy from the book En = E1n * E0, B1=B*(hbar^6)/(m^3), A1=A*m/hbar^2

Below is my solution to this problem of finding the energy eigenvalues by the matrix method, but my energies are completely far from those that should be obtained (the answer is known). Could you please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*basis functions*)
Psi1[r_, n1_] = (2 E^(-(r/n1)) Sqrt[n1!/(-1 + n1)!] Hypergeometric1F1[ 1 - n1, 2, (2 r)/n1])/n1^2;

Psi2[r_, n2_] = (2 E^(-(r/n2)) Sqrt[n2!/(-1 + n2)!] Hypergeometric1F1[ 1 - n2, 2, (2 r)/n2])/n2^2;

(*kinetic energy*)

K[r_, n1_, n2_] = FullSimplify[ Psi2[r, n2]* Laplacian[Psi1[r, n1], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"]];

(*potential energy*)
A1 = 2; B1 = 1;
P[r_] = A1/r^2 + B1*r^2;

(*calculation of matrix elements*)
EE = Table[-1/2*NIntegrate[K[r, n1, n2]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 15, WorkingPrecision -> 32] + NIntegrate[ Psi2[r, n2]*(P[r])*Psi1[r, n1]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
      MaxRecursion -> 15, WorkingPrecision -> 32], {n1, 1, 20}, {n2, 1, 20}] // Chop;

(*eigenvalues*)
Eeig = Sort[N[Eigenvalues[EE], 5]]

Out[64]= {7.4075, 33.524, 152.85, 462.79, 1105.9, 2271.4, 4201.5, \
7199.8, 11644., 18000., 26852., 38927., 55155., 76743., 1.0530*10^5, 
 1.4307*10^5, 1.9337*10^5, 2.6148*10^5, 3.5725*10^5, 5.0488*10^5}

(*Energy from Landau, l=0*)
Energy = N[Table[(Sqrt[B1/2]*(4*n + 2 + Sqrt[8*A1])), {n, 1, 20}]]

Out[65]= {7.07107, 9.89949, 12.7279, 15.5563, 18.3848, 21.2132, \
24.0416, 26.8701, 29.6985, 32.5269, 35.3553, 38.1838, 41.0122, \
43.8406, 46.669, 49.4975, 52.3259, 55.1543, 57.9828, 60.8112}
```

Comment: @yarchik, thanks! Could you explain please, how to understand if a set of basis functions is complete?

Comment: @yarchik, could you please answer this question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278117/how-to-write-expression-of-the-motion-functions-in-coulomb-field-so-that-it-can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a complete system of basis functions, e.g., of 3d harmonic oscillator
$$\psi_{n,\ell,m}(r)=(-1)^ne^{-1/2r^2}r^\ell\sqrt{\frac{2n!}{\Gamma(n+\ell+3/2)}}L_{n}^{\ell+1/2}(r^2)Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi).$$
Next, we consider only spherical symmetric case as you did:
$$\psi_{n}(r)=(-1)^ne^{-1/2r^2}\sqrt{\frac{2n!}{\Gamma(n+3/2)}}L_{n}^{1/2}(r^2).$$

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*basis functions*)

Psi[r_, n_] := (-1)^n E^(-1/2 r^2)
    Sqrt[2 n!/Gamma[n + 3/2]] LaguerreL[n, 1/2, r^2];

(*kinetic energy*)

K[r_, n1_, n2_] := FullSimplify[
   Psi[r, n2] * Laplacian[Psi[r, n1], {r, θ, ϕ}, "Spherical"]];

(*potential energy*)
P[r_] := 1/r^2 + r^2;

(*calculation of matrix elements*)
EE = Table[-1/2 * NIntegrate[K[r, n1, n2] * r^2, {r, 0, ∞}] 
      + NIntegrate[Psi[r, n2]* P[r] *Psi[r, n1] * r^2, {r, 0, ∞}],
     {n1, 0, 5}, {n2, 0, 5}]
```

and compare results of diagonalization

```
Eeig = Sort[N[Eigenvalues[EE], 5]]
{3.57291, 6.49246, 9.56435, 13.072, 17.241, 20.5572}
```

with exact energies

```
e[a_, b_, n_] := Sqrt[b/2] (4 n + 2 + Sqrt[1 + 8 a])
Table[e[1, 1, n] // N, {n, 0, 5}]
{3.53553, 6.36396, 9.19239, 12.0208, 14.8492, 17.6777}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @MamMam   https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteOrthogonalSystem.html Your system of basis functions is not complete because you exclude the functions of continuous spectrum.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow take into account the basis functions of the continuous spectrum, and solve the problem on this complete set?

Comment: @MamMam I hope you realize that already your original post is outside the scope of this forum. Now you drive the discussion in even more irrelevant direction. I suggest you discuss such questions with your teaching instructor or supervisor.