# Eigenvalues of Coulomb potential

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, eigenvalues

As it turned out in the previous question ([Eigenvalues of A/r^2 + B*r^2 potential](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277223/eigenvalues-of-a-r2-br2-potential)), in order to find the energies by the matrix method, it is necessary to have a complete set of basis functions. @yarchik proposed suggested taking the functions of 3d harmonic oscillator as such a set. Now I tried to find the eigenvalues of the system with the Coulomb potential, using the functions of the harmonic oscillator as the basis functions. For simplicity, consider the case when l=0.

Hamiltonian:
**H = -1/2Laplacian -1/r** 
The basis functions: Psi[r_, n_] := (-1)^n E^(-1/2 r^2) Sqrt[2 n!/Gamma[n + 3/2]] LaguerreL[n, 1/2, r^2]; (3d harmonic oscillator functions (l=0)) 
The eigenvalues of the energies should be the following: E=-1/2*n^2 (n = 1, 2,...) (E = -0.5, -0.125, -0.0555556, -0.03125, -0.02, -0.0138889, -0.0102041, -0.0078125, -0.00617284, -0.005, -0.00413223, -0.00347222, -0.00295858, -0.00255102, -0.00222222, -0.00195313, -0.0017301, -0.00154321, -0.00138504, -0.00125,...)

Could you explain why I get completely different values?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*basis functions*)
Psi[r_, n_] := (-1)^n E^(-1/2 r^2) Sqrt[2 n!/Gamma[n + 3/2]] LaguerreL[ n, 1/2, r^2];

(*kinetic energy*)
K[r_, n1_, n2_] := FullSimplify[Psi[r, n2]* Laplacian[Psi[r, n1], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"]];

(*potential energy*)
P[r_] := -(1/r);

(*calculation of matrix elements*)
EE = Table[-1/2*NIntegrate[K[r, n1, n2]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}] + NIntegrate[ Psi[r, n2]*P[r]*Psi[r, n1]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}], {n1, 1, 20}, {n2, 1, 20}];

(*eigenvalues*)
Eeig = Sort[Eigenvalues[EE]]


Out[88]= {-0.131699, 0.105828, 0.484106, 0.987209, 1.61312, 2.34686, \
3.22968, 4.23213, 5.40679, 6.69991, 8.19655, 9.8176, 11.6973, \
13.7135, 16.0828, 18.6123, 21.6818, 24.9717, 29.3094, 34.1404}

(*eigenvalues to be obtained from the analytical solution*)
N[Table[-(1/(2*n^2)), {n, 1, 20}]]

Out[89]= {-0.5, -0.125, -0.0555556, -0.03125, -0.02, -0.0138889, \
-0.0102041, -0.0078125, -0.00617284, -0.005, -0.00413223, \
-0.00347222, -0.00295858, -0.00255102, -0.00222222, -0.00195313, \
-0.0017301, -0.00154321, -0.00138504, -0.00125}
```

Comment: add full correct eigenvalue numbers in question

Comment: @Alrubaie do you mean all 20 numbers? But their number may change depending on how many basis functions I use.

Comment: @yarchik, could you please comment on this issue.

Comment: If you push the basis size to infinity you should be able to achieve that. But the convergence is bad. For every problem the appropriate basis should be used. But how to know what is the appropriate basis? There is no universal solution. However, asymptotic behavior of the eigenfunctions offers some hints. We know, for instance, that eigenfunctions of $1/r$ decay exponentially. On the other hands eigenfunctions of $r^2$ decay as $e^{-r^2}$, i.e., much faster. It requires many terms in the sum to express  the former in terms of the latter.

Comment: Did you forget `n=0` perhaps, I mean `Psi[r,0]`? You also know the ground state, `2*Exp[-r]`, and you can project it onto the subspace spanned by your `Psi` functions.

Comment: @user293787 thanks! I did the calculations by changing n from 0 to 20, the following values ​​were obtained: {-0.498186, -0.106185, 0.13063, 0.499543, 0.989774, 1.61363, 2.3535, 3.23982, 4.24257, 5.41412, 6.70517, 8.19971, 9.81994, 11.6987, 13.7147, 16.0835, 18.613, 21.6823, 24.9722, 29.3096, 34.1408}

Comment: @yarchik thanks! In fact, I deliberately put 1 there, because for the Coulomb potential in the region of the discrete spectrum, the radial eigenwave functions are numbered from 1 and this number is included in the energy. Those the ground state is numbered 1. The functions of the harmonic oscillator are numbered from 0. And I don't understand how n in the Coulomb potential problem is related to the oscillator problem. If it's not difficult for you, could you explain this point.

Comment: @MamMam There is no particular relation. It is simply historically that $n$ for harmonic oscillator starts with $0$, whereas for the Hydrogen atom with 1. The explicit expressions for the wave-functions use this convention. It is of course important to keep the ground state wave-function $n=0$ in the expansion.

Comment: @yarchik, thanks, could you tell me please, in which source the wave functions of the 3d harmonic oscillator are presented in this form?

Comment: See for instance Eq.(1.3) in Genest, V.X., Vinet, L. and Zhedanov, A., 2013. Interbasis expansions for the isotropic 3D harmonic oscillator and bivariate Krawtchouk polynomials. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical, 47(2), p.025202.

Comment: @yarchik, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speed up your calculations by doing some things analytically

```
nmx = 30;
hm = ConstantArray[0, {nmx + 1, nmx + 1}];
Do[
  hm[[1 + n1, 1 + n2]] = KroneckerDelta[n1 - n2]*(n1 + 3/4) - 
   Sqrt[(2 (n1)^2 + (n1))/8] KroneckerDelta[n1 - n2 - 1]
   + NIntegrate[Psi[r, n2] * P[r] * Psi[r, n1] * r^2, {r, 0, ∞}];
  hm[[1 + n2, 1 + n1]] = hm[[1 + n1, 1 + n2]];
 ,{n1, 0, nmx}, {n2, 0, n1}]
```

This approach, using 30 basis functions already gives two bound states.

```
Eigenvalues[hm] // Sort
(*{-0.498937, -0.119135, 0.0403057, 0.284206,...}*)
```

and with 40 basis functions (here one should use analytic integration `Integrate` instead of numeric one) it improves to

```
(*{-0.499283, -0.122884, 0.000297139, 0.180422,...}*)
```

Exact values are $-0.5, -0.125,\ldots$, or analytically
$$
E_n=-\frac12\frac1{n^2},\quad n=1,2,\ldots.
$$

For completeness, as a basis we use angular-independent (i.e., $\ell=0$) eigenfunctions of the isotropic 3d harmonic oscillator
$$\psi_{n}(r)=(-1)^ne^{-1/2r^2}\sqrt{\frac{2n!}{\Gamma(n+3/2)}}L_{n}^{1/2}(r^2), \quad n=0,1,\ldots$$
Here $L_n^{\alpha}$ is the [Laguerre polynomial](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL3/).

Calculation of the matrix elements of the kinetic energy is done analytically. Only the remaining matrix elements of the Coulomb potential $V_{m,n}$ are computed numerically:
$$
V_{m,n}=\int_0^\infty r^2 \psi_{m}(r)\frac{1}{r}\psi_{n}(r)dr=
\int_0^\infty r \psi_{m}(r)\psi_{n}(r)dr.
$$
To speed up the calculation, we explicitly use that the Hamiltonian matrix is symmetric.

Comment: Thanks! With an increase in the number of basic wave functions, Mathematica begin to produce incorrect values. For example, if I take the number of basis functions equal to 40, then the eigenvalues will be as follows {-9400.85, -129.754, -0.499035, -0.116645, 0.0145798, 0.212627, \
0.455479, 0.736404, 1.16453, 1.67823, 2.20157, 2.73062, 3.36413, \
4.13447, 4.96537, 5.84362, 6.8199, 7.88765, 8.94631, ... This seems to be due to the fact that some of the matrix elements are very large. Because of this, more accurate eigenvalues are not obtained. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: @MamMam Actually, all these integrals can be computed analytically with `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate`. The results are good then (see update).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation